# Removing last comma or delimiter from the list c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 DrExistingData = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    if (DrExistingData.HasRows)
                     {
                        string participant = "";
                        string participants = "";

                         while (DrExistingData.Read())
                         {
                             participant = DrExistingData["Name"].ToString();
                             participants = participant + " , " + participants; 

                         }

                             Participant.Text = participants;
                       }
```

Participant is a textbox which is showing the list of names separated by commas but the problem is that the last name is also followed by a comma like:

Simren,Preety,jyoti,
i want to remove the last comma from this list. Please help

Answer (score 8):

Use [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) on your TextBox Text.

```
Participant.Text = participants.TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way to do this is to special-case the first value - also noting that I'm using a `StringBuilder` rather than string-concatenation in a loop (which is pretty brutal for allocations):

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
if(DrExistingData.Read()) {
    builder.Append(DrExistingData["Name"]);
    while(DrExistingData.Read()) {
        builder.Append(',').Append(DrExistingData["Name"]);
    }
}
Participant.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

As another way to do your stuff is to use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
var participants = new List<string>();
while (DrExistingData.Read())
{
    participants.Add(DrExistingData["Name"].ToString());
}
Participant.Text = string.Join(",", participants);
```

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks) I was in progress with adding example)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4 you can do

```
var drExistingData = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
participants.Text = string.Join(", ", 
                                drExistingData.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                                              .Select(record => record["Name"].ToString()));
```

For .Net 3.5 and earlier you must add an `.ToArray()`

```
var drExistingData = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
participants.Text = string.Join(", ", 
                                drExistingData.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                                              .Select(record => record["Name"].ToString())
                                              .ToArray());
```